# why my model not predicting the real world text properly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am building a model for sentiment analysis. my model got 95% accuracy in training and 85% in evaluation.

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers import Embedding, SpatialDropout1D, LSTM, Dense

data = pd.read_csv('Sentiment.csv')
data = data[['text','sentiment']]
data = data[data['sentiment'] != 'Neutral']

#data cleaning 
print('Data cleaning')

data['text'] = data['text'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
data['text'] = data['text'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', '', x))

for idx,row in data.iterrows():
    row[0] = row[0].replace('rt','')

#Vectorizing 
print('Vectorizing...')

tokenizer = Tokenizer(2000, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['text'].values)
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['text'].values)
X = pad_sequences(X)

y = pd.get_dummies(data['sentiment'].values)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

#training 
print('training...')

model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(2000, 128, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(196, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

print('Fitting....')

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=7)

print(model.evaluate(X_test, y_test))

print('----------Completed-----------')
```

But if I tried with give real world sentence . it was predicted wrong. Anyone help me why this happening . i tried with a larger dataset also . but it that also predicted "love" as negative . am I did anything wrong.

```
def tokenize(text):
    sentence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
    sentence = pad_sequences(sentence)
    pred = model.predict(np.array(sentence))
    if np.argmax(pred) == 0:
        print('Negative Sentence')
    else:
        print('Positive Sentence')
tokenize('hate')
```

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step
Positive Sentence

Comment: Are you "tokenizing" differently during prediction than you did for training?  I don't have much experience with NLP, but I do for other forms of supervised learning, and usually you want to do any preprocessing the same for prediction as you did for training. (not fit a preprocessing pipeline to a training set, then refit it to the dataset you're predicting)

Comment: Does your training data contain one word "sentences"? The main assumption in the standard supervised learning problem is that your new data will be drawn from the same fixed distribution that the training data was drawn from. If you try to predict on data drawn from a different distribution, you should expect a loss of accuracy.

Comment: Thank you joe. Now its working . i not added " tokenizer = Tokenizer(2000, split=' ') " this line during prediction .